# php (codeigniter) - simpletest unit testing w/ session data

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeigniter, tdd, simpletest

So I've got simpletest set up with codeigniter ( https://github.com/ericbarnes/codeigniter-simpletest )

I've got some simple tests running and things look good. But I'm hitting a block. I don't know how to test using session data.

The thing is, tests are working just fine. But I'm getting some exceptions. If I run my tests separately (i.e., anything but the "all" tab in simpletest) then there's no issues. And when I do run "all" tests, I get this error:

Unexpected PHP error [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ***/www/public/tests/simpletest/extensions/my_reporter.php:193)] severity [E_WARNING] in [ ***/www/system/libraries/Session.php line 408]Blockquote

Now I'm guessing that it's all using my browser to set sessions and that you can't set/unset them after the first test case is complete (in my case, there's a user model test case which completes, and then the second test case (authentication library), which has the exception.

I'm guessing that after the first test case is done, the headers have already been sent.

```
    <?php
class test_auth extends CodeIgniterUnitTestCase
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->UnitTestCase('Authorization Library');
        $this->rand_good = rand(500,15000);
        $this->rand_bad = rand(500,15000);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_ci->db->flush_cache();
        $this->_ci->db->truncate('users');
        $this->_ci->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->_ci->session->unset_userdata('logged_in_id');

        $u = new User();
        $u->email = 'email' . $this->rand_good;
        $u->password = 'pass' . $this->rand_good;
        $u->confirm_password = 'pass' . $this->rand_good;
        $u->save();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $u = new User();
        $u->get();
        foreach($u->all as $user)
        {
            $user->delete();
        }
    }

    public function test_login_good_email_good_password()
    {
        $u = new User();
        $u->email = 'email' . $this->rand_good;
        $u->password = 'pass' . $this->rand_good;
        $this->assertTrue($this->_ci->auth->login($u), 'login');
        $this->assertTrue($this->_ci->auth->is_logged_in(), 'is logged in');            
    }

    public function test_login_bad_email_bad_password()
    {
        $u = new User();
        $u->email = 'email' . $this->rand_bad;
        $u->password = 'pass' . $this->rand_bad;
        $this->assertFalse($this->_ci->auth->login($u), 'login');
        $this->assertFalse($this->_ci->auth->is_logged_in(), 'is logged in');
    }

}

/* End of file test_auth.php */
```

The two lines that affect this are the `session->sess_destroy()` and `session->unset_userdata()`

Those lines in either tearDown() or setUp() will cause the same issue. Each one causes a header exception.

I guess I'm hoping I can take the browser part out of the testing and that simpletest can simulate that somehow.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: post some code for starters. I imagine if you are outputting content out in your controller this will be the cause. also check for blank space after any closing ?>. but post controller please

Comment: There's no controller in my code. I posted the testing class though, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `sess_destroy()` method sets a new cookie which modifies header information. So you should just use `unset_userdata()` and clear the fields you know you need to clear for the test to complete properly. Then avoid calling `sess_destroy()` in your tests.

See the `setcookie()` call here: http://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/c39315f13a76/system/libraries/Session.php#cl-401

Comment: Right, but even the unset_userdata() is causing the same exception. My theory is that each test case runs and outputs the results one by one, rather than everything at the end, causing the first test case to be the one with control over the headers.